# Allow edit rollbacks on iOS

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, rollbacks

Sometimes I come across a damaging edit on a post which I want to rollback. Unfortunately, there currently isn't any way to rollback edits from the iOS app.

Can an option be added to allow rolling back edits from the iOS app?

Comment: Unfortunately, the SE traffic doesn't come from the app much, so I believe that it's not much of a priority to improve the app at the moment. Use the mobile browsers instead, it's definitely not the end of the world.

Comment: @Unitato the iOS app did get tons of love and features, e.g. revisions list. Android app got nothing, and will probably never get any features, even if by some miracle they won't shut it down soon. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'll break every iPhone I see for this prejudice against Android lol.

Comment: @Unitato only against SE decision to not hire android developer. (The single developer they had, who created the original app, became the mobile app team leader, and stopped working on the app over a year ago. As it turned out, he was busy writing the same app again from scratch, using a different name.)